# Awstats web interface shows 'Never Updated', but will generate static reports

Tags: awstats

I recently installed awstats 7.3, but I'm having trouble viewing reports through its web interface. The web interface shows "Never updated" and all the data is empty and/or zeros. However, I am able to generate static reports with valid data using the `awstats_buildstaticpages.pl` command.

Output from an update run looks like:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -update -config=www.mysite.com -configdir=/etc/awstats/

Create/Update database for config "/etc/awstats/awstats.www.mysite.com.conf" by AWStats version 7.3 (build 20140126)
From data in log file "/var/log/httpd/access_log"...
Phase 1 : First bypass old records, searching new record...
Direct access after last parsed record (after line 566848)
Flush history file on disk (unique hosts reach flush limit of 20000)
Flush history file on disk (unique hosts reach flush limit of 20000)
Jumped lines in file: 566848
 Found 566848 already parsed records.
Parsed lines in file: 2029062
 Found 35 dropped records,
 Found 0 comments,
 Found 0 blank records,
 Found 325 corrupted records,
 Found 0 old records,
 Found 2028702 new qualified records.
```

- AWStats is in `/usr/local/awstats` (with `tools` and `wwwroot` directories inside).
- The configuration file is in `/etc/awstats/awstats.www.mysite.com.conf`
- The `DirData` is `/usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/stats-db`. It contains two data files that look as expected (for this month and last).  I changed this from `/var/lib/awstats` to be sure it was readable by the webserver user (and I verified that it is, by making the data files temporarily accessible via web browser).
- There are log entries from several virtual hosts in the log file, but the `SiteDomain="www.mysite.com"` and the `HostAliases="mysite.com www.mysite.com 127.0.0.1 localhost"`
- This is running on a RHEL server, and SELinux is not enforcing.

Oddly enough, the `awstats_buildstaticpages.pl` command **will** generate reports that contain all the expected data. It's just the web interface that's broken.

It seems related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/138700/awstats-is-processing-log-files-but-does-not-display-them), but there's no accepted solution there (and the suggestions didn't help either).

I've checked everything I can think of here, shy of diving into the perl code. Any ideas?